# Bootstrapnotifier doesnt recognise later added beacons | Android-Beacon-Library

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

Im working with the Android-Beacon-Library to scan for Beacons and display Informations. In Background Mode I want to send Notifications to the user. But I encountered a Problem during development.

I want to add the Regions my Bootstrapnotifier should look for after the app start because i dont know them at this point.

This is my Code:

In my Applications onCreate Method:

```
mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, new ArrayList<Region>());
```

after i know the beacons a go through my list and add them:

```
for(BeaconModel beacon : mBeaconList) {
   mRegionBootstrap.addRegion(new Region(beacon.getId(),
   Identifier.parse(beacon.getUuid()), 
   Identifier.fromInt(beacon.getMajor()),    
   Identifier.fromInt(beacon.getMinor())));
}
```

On RunTime everything works fine, the beacons are found and i can display informations.

But when i move the app to background, the background service doesnt recognize any of them.

I think the Background service looks only for the array in the constructor.

Is there a way to add Beacons later to Background service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mRegionBootstrap.addRegion(...)` method, but only after a connection has been established to the beacon service, otherwise the call is ignored and you will see `Can't add bootstrap region` in the logs.

I suspect that is what is happening -- it usually takes less than a second for the connection to establish, but timing may be different with an app launched in the background.  Unfortunately, the `onBeaconServiceConnected` callback is not part of the `BootstrapNotifier` interface, so it isn't easy to know when to do this.

Perhaps you can simply defer constructing the `RegionBootstrap` until you know your regions.  There is no reason to construct it earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried to create the Regionbootstrap later at the point i know my regions. But then i encountered an other problem: On first App start everything works fine, but at the second time i didnt find any more beacons, instead the state for every beacon in range was set to 0. I found an other solution to my problem. When i create the Regionbootstrap with an empty region instead of an empty list it works.